# FileNotFoundException in Windows 10 Universal App (UAP)

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, azure-application-insights

I developed and published a Windows Universal App. To track exceptions and the app usage I enabled Application Insights and I can find FileNotFoundException's there with the following Call Stack:

```
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6e58d1
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6ee2a4
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x86bd63
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6e58d1
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6ee2a4
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x86d250
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6e58d1
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6ee2a4
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x880c5e
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6e58d1
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6ee2a4
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x8b3663
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6e58d1
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6ee2a4
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x883601
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6e58d1
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x6ee17e
   at Mindapp!<BaseAddress>+0x7d6276
```

Unfortunately I do not have more information. Is there a trick to get more details about this exception?

Comment: I use AI all the time,  key to getting the most out of it is to actually make sure you write good code from the start,  for example, your code should be wrapped inside a try / catch block.   You can then create an exception yourself and send this to AI,   this way you have control over what happened, where, user info etc,  but you are also handling the error.    This looks to me like an unhandled exception, on compiled code

Comment: My app is something like a diagram editor with and I cannot catch every operation obviously. This is the reason why there is a global exception handler, isnt it?

Comment: I would assume, filenotfound exception, would come from a block of code that says something to do with opening a file, my guess is, this is within a function / method.   that code should be wrapped, You are essentially bubbling up your error, away from the method that created it, and ending up with nonsense, because it's not handled.   my application is for XXX  is not an excuse for not handling errors, especially when you want to have analytics on the errors

Comment: I added custom exceptions and improved the file handling. Lets see, if it helps. I also have a NullReferenceException somewhere. This will be hard to find.

Comment: i believe this is specific to UAP apps now build as .net native now, so much of the useful information is now gone at exception time?

Comment: As below, this is a result of .NET Native compilation. We're working on tooling so that these stack can be rebuilt as a post processing step as well as getting that included in AI.

Answer (score 1):

when deployed, the UWP app is compiled as .net native.  in order to turn the above back into something useful, you'll need something like here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/529e6655-bbf2-4ffa-8dcb-b2691327c389/how-to-translate-stack-traces-from-net-native

> There's unfortunately not a great automatic solution if all you have is the stack trace with the addresses in it.  You can manually decode the information using the native Windows debuggers by opening up your application dll as a "dump":

```
windbg -z Your.App.dll
```

> You can then issue the lm command to find the base address of the DLL in the debugger, and the ln command to translate each of +offset locations back to a symbol (assuming you have the PDB handy).

```
0:000> lm m My.App
start             end                 module name
00000000`00400000 00000000`00a08000   My.App   C (private pdb symbols)  My.App.pdb

0:000> ln 0x00400000+0x00021cc4
(00000000`00421cc4)   My.App!RHBinder__DllMain
```

> It's a bit tedious but it should get the job done.