# UWP Application Insights no call stack for crashes

Tags: c#, windows, azure, uwp, azure-application-insights

I have Application Insights setup for a new UWP project.

I'm receiving all information and crashes correctly however, when I try to view details on an exception I get all information but:

- Call stack unavailable
- Failed Method: Unknown

I'm enabling as so in App.xaml.cs constructor:

```
WindowsAppInitializer.InitializeAsync();
```

Comment: windows 10 uap?  is it a release build?  if you can reproduce the crash, you might want to run fiddler, and see what output went out when AI sends its output, to see what data got sent.  Win 10 release builds are .net native now, so the exception is basically just memory locations and offsets, like C++ code would be...

Comment: for example, see this question with what a `FileNotFoundException` looks like on win10: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33572396/filenotfoundexception-in-windows-10-universal-app-uap/33682117#33682117

Comment: to get full crash dump info for windows 10 UAP apps, you'll probably need to use something like HockeyApp (part of the Application Insights org) see http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone

Answer (score 0):

If you can handle the exception yourself, you can add the stack trace (and whatever else) as custom properties. In our app we use a global exception handler, initialized in the App constructor:

```
CoreApplication.UnhandledErrorDetected += UnhandledError;
```

The handler itself looks roughly like so:

```
private void UnhandledError(object sender, UnhandledErrorDetectedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    try
    {
        eventArgs.UnhandledError.Propagate();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                { "trace", e.StackTrace },
                { "mesage", e.Message },
            };

        telemetryClient.TrackCrash(e, properties);
    }
}
```